# Can you show how that RSA does/doesn't provide anonymity?

Tags: encryption, rsa, anonymity

Considering a CPA-secure version of RSA where the ciphertext is just a rundom element from $Z^*_N$. Does that meet the anonymity requirement in which an cpa adversary cannot distinguish between a message encrypted using Alice's public key and a message encrypted using Bob's public key?

EDIT:

My question is related to the experiment in which the adversary is given Alice's public key $pk_A$ and bob's public key $pk_B$ and choose a message $m$ from $Z^*_N$. Then the adversary given the ciphertext created by encryption using $pk_A$ or $pk_B$. The adversary task is to tell what public key has been used.

Comment: Hint: what are the expected maximum and mean value of the ciphertext after a number of messages?

Comment: This is a direction but I'm talking about the cpa experiment. Adding it to the question.

Comment: Also, changed the adversary to be CPA, it is not matter though because in public key an eavesdropper is also a cpa.

Comment: My hint is directly relevant to a working strategy for the adversary in the experiment; except _number_ in my hint is 1 in the experiment, thus maximum and mean are the same, and we must average the outcome of a number of experiments.

Comment: The attack fgrieu hinted at isn't possible if both $N$ are close together. For example one could choose the 128 most significant bits of $N$ to be 1.

Comment: Take a look at the paper [Hans-Joachim Knobloch - Breaking Public Keys - How to Determine an Unknown RSA Public Modulus](http://eprint.iacr.org/2012/588) and this related discussion on a crypto mailing list: [Why using asymmetric crypto like symmetric crypto isn't secure](http://lists.randombit.net/pipermail/cryptography/2012-November/003441.html)

Comment: You may also want to look at the paper [Key-Privacy in Public-Key Encryption](http://www.iacr.org/archive/asiacrypt2001/22480568.pdf) for positive results. $\hspace{.58 in}$

Comment: @fgrieu - so the expected maximum is N-1 (in the case of a quadratic residue group) and the mean is $~e^{n/2} \mod N$? How can I analyze the probability of success here?

Comment: @Bush: Neither (but now that you have added to the question that the adversary is bound to submit a single message per experiment, mean and maximum are moot). I suggest that you compute a rough approximation of the odds that $(m^e\mod N_A)<(m^e\mod N_B)$ for random $m$, as a function of $N_A$ and $N_B$, the public modulus of Alice and Bob; have a mild illumination to define a strategy for the attacker; and compute the advantage obtained by applying this strategy.